# Information about FI-WARE GEis at FI-LAB platform

Tags: fiware

I would like to use the FI-LAB platform at http://lab.fi-ware.org. However, I have doubts about which specific generic enablers instances can I use there or the APIs they are exposing.

Thus, where can I find info about instances of FI-WARE GEs deployed on FI-LAB I can experiment with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good starting point could be the Developers Portal

http://www.fi-ware.org/fi-ware-developers-portal/

There you will find several core components, most of them available at fi-lab. Follow the "more info" link at each Ge, and then check the "Instances" tab in the general Catalogue to obtain more information of where it is deployed or if it is available at fi-lab instance.